# Custom Credit Card regex

Tags: regex

I'm working with a custom credit card validator which has following conditions:

- It must start with a 4,5 or 6.
- It must contain exactly 16 digits.
- It must only consist of digits `(0-9)`.
- It may have digits in groups of 4, separated by one hyphen `-`.
- It must NOT use any other separator like `' '` , `'_'`, etc.
- It must NOT have 4 or more consecutive repeated digits.

I'm not able to find a regex fulfilling the last condition.

I have following regex for other conditions:

```
r'[456][0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}':
```

Comment: I doubt that any real credit card would be following this pattern.  Can you be more specific about how many separators might be present, and where they might be?

Comment: Can you make it two regex? One for checking the first few, and one for just the last condition? E.g., `(\d)-?\1-?\1-?\1` should match four repeated digits (possibly with - in between).

Comment: `It may have digits in groups of` ... you never finished that sentence.  What are the groups?

Comment: `regex` **is not** the appropriate tool to check the last condition. Use other features provided by the language to check it.

Comment: Re-work your definition, as it has many duplicate requirements (`only consist of '-'` vs. `It must NOT use any other separator...`).

Comment: Try [`^(?![-\d]*([0-9])\1{3,})[456][0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/mDTrQp/1/)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry , did the changes

Comment: So it _may_ have digits in groups of 4, but it could also have groups of 2 or 3?  No single credit card behaves this way, I believe, and I think it would be tough to write a single regex to cover this requirement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually this is not for an actual requirement , i'm stuck at a question with these requirements.

Comment: @Thefourthbird this doesn't works

Comment: Perhaps with an optional hyphen in the lookahead: [`^(?![-\d]*([0-9])(?:-?\1){3,})[456][0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/AtUbWv/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks this regex works , could you explain me a bit

Comment: I have added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last condition you could use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that asserts that what follows is not a digit followed by 3 or more times an optional hypen and a digit.

Explanation for the added part `(?![-\d]*([0-9])(?:-?\1){3,})`

- `(?!)` Negative lookahead

  - `[-\d]*` Match zero or more times a digit or a hyphen
  - `([0-9])` Capture a digit in a group
  - `(?:-?\1){3,}` Repeat 3 or more times in a non capturing group an optional hyphen `-?` followed by a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to the digit that is captured in group 1
- `)` Close negative lookahead

Your regex with added anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the line could look like:

[`^(?![-\d]*([0-9])(?:-?\1){3,})[456][0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/AtUbWv/1)